# Bootstrap - Divs stack up on eachother

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If you make the screen smaller (in width) the divs on the bottom (under 'My work') stack up on each other. I was wondering how to fix this?

See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sxnmyjtk/

**html:**

```
  <div class="tiles">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="servatius">
            <p>Servatius</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="levy">
            <p>Levy Consult</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="skinprove">
            <p>Skinprove</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="mumc">
            <p>MUMC+</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**see jsfiddle for css**

Comment: @Piinthesky, sorry! you're right. I changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are stacking on top of each other because you are using position absolute in your CSS. If you remove this they will then stack vertically when the width is reduced.

If you want the divs to remain side by side you can also consider using col-xs-3 instead of col-md-3.

You can add other bootstrap classes or CSS depending on what results you are tying to achieve when width is reduced.